Question about rank of the module $\frac{M}{N}$
Let $A$ be an integral domain and let $M$ and $N$ be finitely generated $A$-modules such that $N \subset M$. A book I am reading asserts that the module $\frac{M}{N}$ is of rank $rank(M) - rank(N)$ but I do not see why this is true.
The author explains that any finitely generated $A$-module is isomorphic to a quotient $\frac{A^n}{K}$ where $K$ is a sub module of $A^n$. Thus we can also deduce that $N$ is isomorphic to $\frac{P}{K}$ where $P$ is a sub module of $A^n$ containing $K$. The author also explains that any for $A$-module $M$, $\frac{M}{Tor(M)}$ can be embedded in a $Frac(A)$-vector space $E$ via a map $u$ and thus since $M$ is isomorphic to $\frac{A^n}{K}$ this gives us a way to compute the rank:
$$rank(M) = n - dim(vect(u(K)))$$
With these facts I am still not able to conclude that $rank \left( \frac{M}{N} \right) = rank(M) - rank(N)$. However if $A$ is a PID I am able to deduce the following:
If $M$ is isomorphic to $\frac{A^n}{K}$, since $A$ is a PID $K$ is a free module thus $dim(vect(u(K))) = rank(K)$ and we obtain $rank(M) = n - rank(K)$. And since $N$ is isomorphic to $\frac{P}{K}$ we may use the fact that $P$ and $K$ are sub modules of $A^n$ to deduce that they are free and once again obtain that $rank(N) = rank(P) - rank(K)$. Now we can use the fact that $\frac{M}{N}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\frac{A^n}{K}}{\frac{P}{K}}$ which is isomorphic to $\frac{A^n}{P}$. And in a similar way to what was done above we obtain that $rank \left( \frac{M}{N} \right) = n - rank(P) = n - rank(N) - rank(K) = rank(M) - rank(N)$.
Above I have used that $A$ is a PID but when $A$ is just an integral domain I am not sure how to adapt the proof.

In fact, $\mathrm{rank}(M)=\dim_{Q(A)}Q(M)$, where $Q(A)$ is the field of fractions of $A$, and $Q(M)=S^{-1}M$, where $S=A\setminus{0}$. Then use that localization commutes with the quotients of modules.
